# Optimize delete SQL query with unordered table

Tags: sql, query-optimization, sybase

I am attempting a mass delete of old data from a huge table with 80,000,000 rows, about 50,000,000 rows will be removed. This will be done in batches of 50k to avoid database log overflow. Also the rows of the table are not sorted chronologically. I've come up with the following script:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE  @START_TIME DATETIME,
         @END_TIME  DATETIME,
         @DELETE_COUNT NUMERIC(10,0),
         @TOTAL_COUNT NUMERIC(10,0),
         @TO_DATE DATETIME,
         @FROM_DATE DATETIME,
         @TABLE_SIZE INT
     
SELECT @START_TIME = GETDATE()
PRINT 'Delete script Execution START TIME = %1!', @START_TIME

SELECT @TABLE_SIZE = COUNT(*) FROM HUGE_TABLE
PRINT 'Number of rows in HUGE_TABLE = %1!', @TABLE_SIZE

SELECT @DELETE_COUNT = 1,
       @TOTAL_COUNT  = 0,
       @TO_DATE = DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())
       
CREATE TABLE #TMP_BATCH_FOR_DEL (REQUEST_DT DATETIME)

WHILE(@DELETE_COUNT > 0)
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM #TMP_BATCH_FOR_DEL
    
    INSERT INTO #TMP_BATCH_FOR_DEL (REQUEST_DT)
    SELECT TOP 50000 REQUEST_DT
        FROM HUGE_TABLE 
        WHERE REQUEST_DT < @TO_DATE
        ORDER BY REQUEST_DT DESC
    
    SELECT @FROM_DATE = MIN(REQUEST_DT), @TO_DATE = MAX(REQUEST_DT)
    FROM #TMP_BATCH_FOR_DEL

    PRINT 'Deleting data from %1! to %2!', @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE

    DELETE FROM HUGE_TABLE
    WHERE REQUEST_DT BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE
    
    SELECT @DELETE_COUNT = @@ROWCOUNT
    
    SELECT @TOTAL_COUNT = @TOTAL_COUNT + @DELETE_COUNT
    
    SELECT @TO_DATE = @FROM_DATE
    
    COMMIT
    CHECKPOINT

END 

SELECT @END_TIME = GETDATE()
PRINT 'Delete script Execution END TIME = %1!', @END_TIME
PRINT 'Total Rows deleted = %1!', @TOTAL_COUNT
DROP TABLE #TMP_BATCH_FOR_DEL
END
GO
```

I did a practice run and found the above was deleting around 2,250,000 rows per hour. So, it would take 24+ hours of continuous runtime to delete my data.

I know it's that darn ORDER BY clause within the loop that's slowing things down, but storing the ordered table in another temp table would take up too much memory. But, I can't think of a better way to do this.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably not the query itself.  Your code is deleting about 600+ records *per second*.  A lot is going on in that time -- logging, locking, and so on.

A faster approach is to load the data you want into a new table, truncate the old table, and reload it:

```
select *
into temp_huge_table 
from huge_table
where request_dt > ?;  -- whatever the cutoff is
```

Then -- after validating the results -- truncate the huge table and reload the data:

```
truncate table huge_table;

insert into huge_table
    select *
    from temp_huge_table;
```

If there is an identity column you will want to disable that to allow identity insert.  You might have to take other precautions if there are triggers that set values in the table.  Or if there are foreign key references to rows in the table.

I would not suggest doing this directly.  After you have truncated the table, you should probably partition by the table by date -- by day, week, month, whatever.

Then, in the future, you can simply drop partitions rather than deleting rows.  Dropping partitions is much, much faster.

Note that loading a few tens of millions of rows into an empty table is much, much faster than deleting them, but it still takes time (you can test how much time on your system).  This requires downtown for the table.  However, you hopefully have a maintenance period where this is possible.

And, the downtime can be justified by partitioning the table so you won't have this issue in the future.

Comment: I suppose it would work... But would inserting millions of rows into a new table at once effect the database logs? Would a batch insert be necessary?

Comment: Just did some research on different methods of bulk importing/exporting data. I think this should work for my use case. Thx for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can optimize your Query by Inserting the 30.000.000 Records you want to keep into antoher Table which will be your new "Huge Table". And Drop the whole old "Huge Table" all together.

Best Regards

LK